# Lock menu option not appearing in TortoiseGit->LFS menu

Tags: locking, tortoisegit

I'm using the following version of TortoiseGit for Windows:

TortoiseGit 2.12.0.0
git version 2.34.1.windows.1

I have included a .gitattributes file in the folder with the following info:

*.* filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text lockable

The context menu for TortoiseGit contains the menu option for LFS but that menu only contains the option "Show locked files" - it does not have a menu option for "Lock" though the TortoiseGit documentation states:

*In order to edit a lockable file you need to lock it using context menu via TortoiseGit → LFS → Lock.*

Can someone please help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the file already version controlled?

Comment: Yes, I added it to version control by using commit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the context menu entry *TortoiseGit → LFS → Lock* appears only when you right-click a **file**.

The context menu entry *TortoiseGit → LFS → Show locked files* appears only when you right-click a **folder**.

Found in TortoiseGit 2.13.0.1